# webmin - how to connect multiple apache instances on the machine?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, webmin

I have multiple Apache servers on the machine and would like to manage them via Webmin, but cannot find the way.

Perhaps, there is a module or some tricks?

Running under Ubuntu 22.04

Thanks.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/install-and-use-webmin-in-ubuntu-22-04/ If you follow these instructions, where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Gantendo I have no options to add another apache servers, running on my machine. The Webmin does not "see" them too. They work on different ports, but Webmin shows only a preinstalled system Apache. Can you show, please, how do you connect the other instances of Apache to the Webmin by this reference? Thx